# PHP cURL submit to WSDL SOAP environment

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I've never had the opportunity to submit to a WSDL SOAP web service and am running into some issues. Im using PHP cURL to submit the form to a known back end fist, then secondly to the WSDL SOAP service. The first part is working fine, so I will skip over that. I have spent the better part of 3 days trying different solutions I've found on the web, and my own after reading SOAP documentation, with no luck.

Here is what I'm using to submit to the WSDL

```
<?php
    //first cURL POST HERE - works fine
    //second cURL POST BELOW
    $FName          = $_POST['FirstName'];
    $Lname          = $_POST['LastName'];
    $Email          = $_POST['Email'];
    $Phone          = $_POST['Phone1'];
    $soapURL            = "https://something.com/IBWeb/IBDemoManager/IBDemoManager.asmx?wsdl";
    $soapUser           = "USR";
    $soapPassword       = "PWD";
    $hostname           = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    $xml_post_string = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservices.htdocs.openecry">
                          <soapenv:Header/>
                           <soapenv:Body>
                              <web:demosetup soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
                                 <AccessCode xsi:type="xsd:string">G0!=@%fut40</AccessCode>
                                 <NewUserCategoryName xsi:type="xsd:string">OFLDemo</NewUserCategoryName>
                                 <TemplateUserName xsi:type="xsd:string">OFLUser</TemplateUserName>
                                 <CusType xsi:type="xsd:string">Indirect</CusType>
                                 <WLabelID xsi:type="xsd:string">276</WLabelID>
                                 <SCodeID xsi:type="xsd:string"></SCodeID>
                                 <SoftID xsi:type="xsd:string">1</SoftID>
                                 <FName xsi:type="xsd:string">'.$FName.'</FName>
                                 <LName xsi:type="xsd:string">'.$LName.'</LName>
                                 <Email xsi:type="xsd:string">'.$Email.'</Email>
                                 <Phone xsi:type="xsd:string">'.$Phone.'</Phone>
                                 <Address xsi:type="xsd:string"></Address>
                                 <City xsi:type="xsd:string"></City>
                                 <Zip xsi:type="xsd:string"></Zip>
                                 <State xsi:type="xsd:string"></State>
                                 <Country xsi:type="xsd:string"></Country>
                                 <CountryName xsi:type="xsd:string"></CountryName>
                                 <AssetTypes xsi:type="xsd:string">Futures</AssetTypes>
                                 <How xsi:type="xsd:string">OFL webservice</How>
                                 <MoreEmail xsi:type="xsd:string"></MoreEmail>
                                 <RemoteAddr xsi:type="xsd:string">'.$hostname.'</RemoteAddr>
                                 <CampaignID xsi:type="xsd:string"></CampaignID>
                              </web:demosetup>
                           </soapenv:Body>
                        </soapenv:Envelope>';

    $headers = array(
        "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
        "Accept: text/xml",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Pragma: no-cache",
        //IS SOAPAction the same as the endpoint "$soapURL"?//
        "SOAPAction: https://something.com/IBWeb/IBDemoManager/IBDemoManager.asmx?wsdl", 
        "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
    );

    $url2 = $soapURL;
    $soap_do = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL, $url2 );
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        100);
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $xml_post_string);
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $headers);
      if(curl_exec($soap_do) === false) {
        $err = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($soap_do);
        curl_close($soap_do);
        print $err;
      } else {
        $result = curl_exec($soap_do);
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($result);
        curl_close($soap_do);
        //print 'Operation completed without any errors';
      }
```

Comment: `and am running into some issues`. Could you please add more details about the error message?

Comment: I'm not getting anything back from the webservice, or I don't have it set up correctly to display it. I'm just displaying in console what I submit so I know it matches up w/what Im expecting to submit.

Comment: I updated w/code to display returned error. I get a large xml wrapper back, and the last line is "<item xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
          <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">Result</key>
          <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">Error: Duplicate user account!</value>
        </item>" which is strange since I'm using a made up email address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are just some comments:

Try to disable the SSL check (just for testing):

```
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

You should call `curl_close($ch2);` as last. Example:

```
$output2 = curl_exec($ch2); 

if(curl_errno($ch2))
    echo curl_error($ch2);
} else {
    echo $output2;
}

curl_close($ch2); // <--- close here
```

You could also try the [Zend SOAP library](https://gist.github.com/odan/1a736eefabe893fa66e4befeb226dcc8#creating-a-soap-client).

If you don't like CURL try [Guzzle](https://github.com/meng-tian/async-soap-guzzle) to make an HTTP request.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my request do return the error from the service, and it's getting hung up on a duplicate account. which is impossible since I'm making up the email address for testing. I will test your suggestions as well